# How do I identity the Chrome extension that is causing console error: Refused to execute inline script because it violates

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-developer-tools

I was using Chrome developer tools to debug an issue with a website, and I noticed that for every website I visit, this Console error shows at least once:

> utils.js:3474 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-lr7yBeMxuhPGBcG1D4v/KX2hae9FXooEYNrKFrADj2E='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I assume this is caused by a Chrome extension. Is there an easy way to identity **which** Chrome extension is causing this error?

When I click on the "utils.js" file it contains this gibberish comment at the top, which is probably a clue, although I cannot find anything via a google search:

```
// This script contains a badly-organised collection of miscellaneous
// functions that really better homes.
```

Comment: When I google "This script contains a badly-organised collection of miscellaneous", I get a single result: https://searchcode.com/file/56612/testing/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js/

Comment: "I assume this is caused by a Chrome extension" - Why do you assume this? Have you disabled all Chrome extensions and **not** received the same error?

Comment: @ThomasMueller yes. But my question is, is there a way to tell which Chrome extension is causing a specific console error? The only way to discover that is by turning them all off, and then turning them back on one-by-one (this particular one seems to be caused by the Blazemeter extension). I'm wondering if that is only way to solve the issue.

Comment: When you hover util.js it may already show the extension id in its URL, otherwise use a file manager (or `ls -R`) to find `util.js` in your browser profile's `Extensions` folder.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm, please add your comment as an answer so I can select it. I found the offending javascript file in my "Extensions" folder, which for my version of Chrome is in C:\Users\[my login]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Extensions